# Using R to optimize parameters of a function

Tags: r, optimization

I am acquainted with the optimization functions in R.  I tried three different ways:

```
library(optimx)
library(optimr)

f = function(par){20*par[1] - 3*par[1]^2 + par[1] * par[2]}

# First try wiht optim()

result1 = optim(par = c(0,0), fn = f, upper = c(5, 2), lower = c(0, 0), method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(fnscale = -1))
coef(result1) # Null

# Second try with optimr

result2 = optimr(par = c(0,0), fn = f, upper = c(5, 2), lower = c(0, 0), method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(maximize = TRUE))
coef(result2) # Null

# Third try with optimx

result3 = optimx(par = c(0,0), fn = f, upper = c(5, 2), lower = c(0, 0), method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(maximize = TRUE))
coef(result3)

p1 : 3.666667
p2  : 2
```

Why optim() and optimr() fail where optimx() succeeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `f` takes two arguments rather than a vector of length two (you need the latter). Second, it's not `coef` what gives the result; I suspect that you want `result$par`. Hence,

```
library(optimr)
f <- function(x) -(20 * x[1] - 3 * x[1]^2 + x[2] / 2)

result <- optimr(par = c(1, 1), fn = f, upper = c(5, 2), lower = c(0, 0), 
                 method = "L-BFGS-B")
result$par
# [1] 3.333333 2.000000
```

where I added a minus sign to `f` to minimize the function as `optimr` somehow was unable to maximize it.

Comment: That's clearly not the right answer 0,0 does not maximize the function

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade, indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with base `optim` function for your maximization. The problem you are having is that it should be one vector with all the parameters you want to solve 2, not independent parameters. I tried using `optimr` but for some reason it dint maximize.

```
f = function(x){-1*(20*x[1] - 3*x[1]^2 + x[2]/2)}
result = optim(par = c(1,1), fn = f, upper = c(5, 2), lower = c(0, 0), method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the {optimr} package, base R does just fine:

```
optim(
    c(1, 1),
    function (x) -f(x[1], x[2]),
    method = 'L-BFGS-B'
)
```

```
$par
[1] 3.325034e+00 1.682724e+13

$value
[1] -8.413622e+12

$counts
function gradient
      40       40

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

Note that we need to adjust the parameter arity of the function (`optim` uses a single vector of parameters), and, since we want to maximise, we invert the sign of the objective function. Hence we pass `function (x) -f(x[1], x[2])` as `fn` rather than simply `f`.